# GCP Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Run - .NET 5.0 - Application settings from secrets or transform appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, .net-5, google-cloud-run

Using an `Azure App Service` I can edit `Configuration` and read a value from a `Key vault` and set it to my `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` from `appsettings.json` like this:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=My-KeyVault;SecretName=Db-Connection)
```

[image]

This works really well and the database connection string and other secrets are kept secure.

I would like to do something similar with `GCP Cloud Run`.

I followed this guide to get an application up and running and it works:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/net-50-google-cloud

Then it gets a bit trickier though. I have been reading up on the `Preview — Support for Secret Manager secrets in Cloud Run`

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets

My initial thought has been to simply replace `appsettings.json` with a secret file. Is this the best way to go or is there another better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as of the moment, `Secret Manager` through [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager?_ga=2.216839958.1898174372.1633936252-1346153347.1628536115&_gac=1.58520664.1634269862.Cj0KCQjwqp-LBhDQARIsAO0a6aLlWmcRDF04H8qnGMCbr2dw4pgw6SbEFpuwL8v138b2vbKi-aoZjZ4aAkM1EALw_wcB) and client library are the best options for you to manage secrets. You can access Secret Manager secrets and expose them as **environment variables** or via the **filesystem** from Cloud Run services.

Make sure that you [Configure Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/configuring-secret-manager#enable_api) first before you can [create, access and manage secrets](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets).

Answer (score 1):

As @RobertG says and then @Dondi edited, use environment variables.

Use `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` as environment variable and get the value from Secret Manager like this:

[image]